# Query optimization with "one to many to one" joins

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to optimize this query:

```sql
SELECT product.id AS product_id, order_line.quantity AS quantity, 
       order_line.price * order_line.quantity AS line_total
FROM order
JOIN order_line ON order_line.order_id = order.id
JOIN product ON order_line.product_id = product.id
WHERE order.tenant_id = 127211
  AND order.creation_date BETWEEN '2022-05-01' AND '2022-05-31'
  AND product.category_id IN (138970, 803167);
```

`explain analyze` return this:

```
-> Nested loop inner join  (cost=906.13 rows=21) (actual time=38613.854..131412.208 rows=2936 loops=1)
    -> Nested loop inner join  (cost=467.83 rows=429) (actual time=16.207..69918.527 rows=166088 loops=1)
        -> Filter: (product.category_id in (138970,803167))  (cost=6.18 rows=26) (actual time=0.028..0.157 rows=25 loops=1)
            -> Index range scan on product using product_5f2644f7  (cost=6.18 rows=26) (actual time=0.027..0.112 rows=25 loops=1)
        -> Index lookup on order_line using order_line_product_id_74777b959ed71ef9_idx (product_id=product.id)  (cost=16.17 rows=17) (actual time=6.030..2795.863 rows=6644 loops=25)
    -> Filter: ((order.tenant_id = 127211) and (order.creation_date between '2022-05-01' and '2022-05-31'))  (cost=0.92 rows=0) (actual time=0.370..0.370 rows=0 loops=166088)
        -> Single-row index lookup on order using PRIMARY (id=order_line.order_id)  (cost=0.92 rows=1) (actual time=0.368..0.368 rows=1 loops=166088)
```

1. The query begins filtering all products that have the category **ids** `(138970, 803167)`, which returns only 25 rows and is very fast.
2. Then it joins the **`order_line`** table using index lookup. This returns a lot of rows, 166088 to be precise.
3. Then, for each one of these 166088 rows, it does an index lookup using the primary key of the order table and filters the `tenant_id` and `creation_date`. This returns "only" 2936 rows.
4. The total time of the query is about 131 seconds.

I've tried to force the join order: first the `order` table, then `order_line` and last the `product` table. In some cases, this reduces considerably the total time of the query. But in other cases, when I change the filter values (`tenant_id`, `creation_date` and `category_id`), it has the opposite effect. I know that force join order and use of indexes is not a good solution overall, but I gave it a try anyway.

The problem seems to be this huge number of rows in the `order_line` table that is being fetched and discarded afterwards. No matter in what table the filter starts (`order` or `product`) the result is the same: few rows (`order`/`product`) - a lot of rows (`order_line`) - few rows (`product`/`order`). If I could create columns for `creation_date` and `category_id` in the `order_line` table and create an index on them I believe the query would be much faster, because it only would get the order lines it needs, nothing less, nothing more. Unfortunately, I can't do this at the moment.

So my question is, is there anything else I could do to speed up this query?

MySql version is 8.0.23.

Comment: Do you have indexes  & primary foreign keys setup on key fields and foreign key's and the items being "filtered" in your where clause?  specfically the order_ID and product_ID on order_Line?

Comment: @xQbert, yes, all foreign keys have indexes. The index `product_5f2644f7`, that appear in the explain analyze, is on column `category_id` (table `product`) and `order_line_product_id_74777b959ed71ef9_idx` is on column `product_id` (table `order_line`). Also, the `order` table have an index on `tenant_id` and `creation_date`, but MySql didn't use it for this query.

Comment: See [_Many-to-many_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for tips on indexing such tables.

Comment: I really like these tips @RickJames. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Proper indexes are your best friend for querying.  Since your primary consideration is a single Tenant_id and Date/Time of an order, make sure you have a single index (not two individually that contain each column) on

```
Table       Index
Order       ( tenant_id, creation_date, id )  
Order_Line  ( order_id, product_id )
Product     ( id, category_id )
```

To make it a fully qualified covering index, you might also try having an index on `Order_Line` with `(order_id, product_id, price, quantity)`.  This way all the entire query can be processed by use of the indexes directly and never have to get back to the raw data pages to pull the data.

Comment: We already have an index `(tenant_id, creation_date)` in the `order` table, but MySql chooses not to use it. Table `product` also has an index for `category_id`. The only index that we don't have is the `(order_id, product_id)` in the `order_line` table.

Unfortunately, the covering index is not an option too because this is a simplified version of the real query. For the sake of simplicity, I've omitted other joins and columns that are being used.

Comment: The Index on Order that you've suggested (Order       ( tenant_id, creation_date, id )  ) doesn't seems to be optimal, since he uses an inequality operator on creation_date field, hence making the extra id useless for this query.
Perhaps exchanging their order might do some work

Comment: @TauaNegri, the where clause was for tenant_id =, and the category was for between date ranges.  Dont know which inequality operator you are referring to.  So, give me an order for one tenant where the date is within a range.  First gets to the tenant and second jumps directly to the order date range begin/end... very fast

Comment: @DRapp I was reffering to the Join clause with the ID. 

We have two where conditions here: tenant_id and creation_date
But we also need to look for the id in order to do the join, that's why i suggested that a change on the order index that you've suggested might do the trick, this way it should use the index only on this query, with no need to look back at the Orders table to fetch the id

Comment: @TauaNegri, the WHERE clause is the primary consideration of the source record, hence tenant_id and date.  The JOIN will have the ID value for joining to the order line items only AFTER the primary where clause is met.  Since part of the index, that will be fine.  The Order_ID of the line items table is optimal for that portion of the join.